# How to interpret graphical model for Dirichlet process mixture for variational inference?

Tags: graphical-model, bayesian-network, variational-bayes, dirichlet-process, nonparametric-bayes

I am working through [this paper](http://www.cs.columbia.edu/~blei/papers/BleiJordan2004.pdf) by Blei and Jordan, which introduces variational inference for Dirichlet process mixtures. They derive an evidence lower bound (ELBO) function based on a stick breaking construction for Dirichlet process with observations $\mathbf{x}$, latent variables $\mathbf{W}=\{\mathbf{V},\mathbf{\eta}^*,\mathbf{Z}\}$ and hyperparameters $\theta=\{\alpha,\lambda\}$. They introduce the following graphical model:

[image]

I am trying to derive the ELBO in eqn. (16):
[image]

From what I can tell, the first three terms on the right hand side imply that
$$
p(\mathbf{V},\mathbf{\eta}^*,\mathbf{x},\mathbf{Z}\mid\alpha,\lambda)
= p(\mathbf{V}\mid\alpha)\cdot p(\mathbf{\eta}^*\mid\lambda)\cdot p(\mathbf{Z}\mid\mathbf{V})\cdot p(\mathbf{x}\mid\mathbf{Z}),
$$
but I can't reproduce this. Here's what I have:
$$
p(\mathbf{V},\mathbf{\eta}^*,\mathbf{x},\mathbf{Z}\mid\alpha,\lambda)
= p(\mathbf{V}\mid\alpha)\cdot p(\mathbf{\eta}^*\mid\lambda)\cdot p(\mathbf{Z}\mid\mathbf{V})\cdot p(\mathbf{x}\mid\mathbf{Z},\mathbf{\eta}^*).
$$

The only difference between the two is in the last term. I express the dependence of data $\mathbf{x}$ on the latent variable $\mathbf{\eta}^*$. Why doesn't eqn. (16) include this dependence?